# Use variables in for...of object loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, object, ecmascript-6

I have a for...of loop for objects.

```
for(const {site, dt, cat, ...vals} of obj[key]) {
   ...
}
```

code with the help of @user120242:
Original code

```js
let obj= {
  'Jan 01': [
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
            ],
  'Feb 01': [
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:12, val2:11, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:45, val2:67, val3:0},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:78, val2:34, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:88, val3:5},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:56, val2:11, val3:99},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:22, val2:34, val3:77},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:33, val2:99, val3:34},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:77, val2:55, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:23, val3:98}
            ],
  'Mar 01': [
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:11, val2:20, val3:6},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:22, val2:91, val3:89},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:81, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:71, val3:33},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:55, val2:61, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:66, val2:51, val3:43},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:77, val2:41, val3:98},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:88, val2:31, val3:23},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:99, val2:21, val3:4}
            ]
}

for(const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  const catMap = new Map()
  for(const {site, dt, cat, ...vals} of obj[key]) {
    const row = catMap.get(dt+','+cat)||{dt, cat}
    Object.entries(vals).forEach(([k,v])=>row[k]=(row[k]||0)+v)
    catMap.set(dt+','+cat, row)
  }
  obj[key] = [...catMap.values()]
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code with Vars:

```js
let obj= {
  'Jan 01': [
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
            ],
  'Feb 01': [
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:12, val2:11, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:45, val2:67, val3:0},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:78, val2:34, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:88, val3:5},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:56, val2:11, val3:99},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:22, val2:34, val3:77},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:33, val2:99, val3:34},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:77, val2:55, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:23, val3:98}
            ],
  'Mar 01': [
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:11, val2:20, val3:6},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:22, val2:91, val3:89},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:81, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:71, val3:33},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:55, val2:61, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:66, val2:51, val3:43},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:77, val2:41, val3:98},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:88, val2:31, val3:23},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:99, val2:21, val3:4}
            ]
}

let site_val = 'site';
let dt_val = 'dt'
let cat_val = 'cat'

for(const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  const catMap = new Map()
  for(const {site_val, dt_val, cat_val, ...vals} of obj[key]) {
    const row = catMap.get(dt_val+','+cat_val)||{dt_val, cat_val}
    Object.entries(vals).forEach(([k,v])=>row[k]=(row[k]||0)+v)
    catMap.set(dt_val+','+cat_val, row)
  }
  obj[key] = [...catMap.values()]
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use variables instead of `site`, `dt`, `cat` to make it more dynamic. When I use variables, I am getting `undefined`. How do I use variables?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. In the code above, `site`, `dt`, `cat`, etc **are** variables

Comment: @Phil, no, those are object keys for obj[key]

Comment: for(foo of obj[key]) {
   const {site, dt, cat, ...vals} = foo
}

Comment: for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545906/sum-values-of-objects-based-on-other-values-in-object/62546142#62546142

Comment: Is your obj[key] an array of objects? Otherwise, replace `obj[key]` to `[obj[key]]`.

Comment: do you mean: {site: newVarName}?  Or are you saying you want to customize what keys to extract, like {[keyNameVar]: myVar}?

Comment: @JohnnyWong, yes it is

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you mean by _"When I use variables, I am getting undefined"_ by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62546872/edit) to actually show that code

Comment: Is something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jzo35at9/) what you're looking for?

Comment: @user120242, I have.variables for site, dt and cat and wanted to know if I can just replace those values with variables

Comment: @Phil, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545906/sum-values-of-objects-based-on-other-values-in-object/62546142#62546142 for reference

Comment: @Phil, I have added it

Comment: No, you haven't. You said _"When I use variables, I am getting undefined"_ but you have not explained what that means nor have you shown that code

Comment: @nb_nb_nb he means it's unclear what you mean by variables.  I am guessing you want to have an array of keys you filter on, like configuration variables?  Needs more clarification.  If you posted your own attempt at it, it might be easier to direct you to the right solution.  Although I'd guess that you'd still need to clarify what you are trying to do with an input and desired output.

Comment: @user120242, I have added the code with vars to show what I mean

Comment: @Phil, I have added it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring) syntax
`{ [computedName+'str']: varName }`
:

```js
let obj= {
  'Jan 01': [
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Jan 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
            ],
  'Feb 01': [
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:12, val2:11, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:45, val2:67, val3:0},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:78, val2:34, val3:41},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:88, val3:5},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:56, val2:11, val3:99},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:22, val2:34, val3:77},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:33, val2:99, val3:34},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:77, val2:55, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Feb 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:23, val3:98}
            ],
  'Mar 01': [
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'google', val1:11, val2:20, val3:6},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'bing', val1:22, val2:91, val3:89},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'abc', site: 'jeeves', val1:33, val2:81, val3:12},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'google', val1:44, val2:71, val3:33},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'bing', val1:55, val2:61, val3:14},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'pqr', site: 'jeeves', val1:66, val2:51, val3:43},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'google', val1:77, val2:41, val3:98},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'bing', val1:88, val2:31, val3:23},
             {dt: 'Mar 01', cat: 'xyz', site: 'jeeves', val1:99, val2:21, val3:4}
            ]
}

let site_key = 'site';
let dt_key = 'dt'
let cat_key = 'cat'

for(const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  const catMap = new Map()
  for(const {
       [site_key]:site_val,
       [dt_key]:dt_val,
       [cat_key]:cat_val, ...vals} of obj[key]) {
    const row = catMap.get(dt_val+','+cat_val)||{dt_val, cat_val}
    Object.entries(vals).forEach(([k,v])=>row[k]=(row[k]||0)+v)
    catMap.set(dt_val+','+cat_val, row)
  }
  obj[key] = [...catMap.values()]
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```